# Pacemaker + Corosync + DRBD + Samba + NFS

Tags: samba, nfs, pacemaker, drbd, corosync

Hello everybody,

i am trying to setup a 2 PC cluster with shared resources ClusterIP, ClusterSamba, ClusterNFS, DRBD (cloned resource) and a DRBDFS.
The beginning of the project was made following the [Clusters from Scratch](https://clusterlabs.org/pacemaker/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/2.0/html/Clusters_from_Scratch/index.html). And when all together from this guide is done it works without problems. So i wanted to use some chunks from this guide and to make my project where i set up one shared IP (ClusterIP) which is automatically assigned to one node and ( here it begins :/ ) on that node mount my /dev/drbd1 device to /exports and then this mount share through SAMBA and NFS.
When i start the cluster all resources go up as they should, **but DRBD does not go up on secondary node** ( Primary/Unknown ). If I rise it manually it syncs and works, and when I stop the cluster ( or forcibly reboot first node) all resources transfer to other node and everything works ( except that DRBD on other node goes down into Unknown state).
So now, here is the problem: **Why does the DRBD goes down on secondary node when I stop the cluster? Or why doesn't it start in Secondary role on secondary node?**
Sorry if my description is bad :)

Here are the commands I used and lower are configs and results:

```
# apt install -y pacemaker pcs psmisc policycoreutils-python-utils drbd-utils samba nfs-kernel-server 
# systemctl start pcsd.service
# systemctl enable pcsd.service
# passwd hacluster
# pcs host auth alice bob
# pcs cluster setup myCluster alice bob --force
# pcs cluster start --all
# pcs property set stonith-enabled=false
# pcs property set no-quorum-policy=ignore
# modprobe drbd
# echo drbd >/etc/modules-load.d/drbd.conf
# drbdadm create-md r0
# drbdadm up r0
# drbdadm primary r0 --force
# mkfs.ext4 /dev/drbd1
# systemctl disable smbd
# systemctl disable nfs-kernel-server.service 
# mkdir /exports
# vi /etc/samba/smb.conf 
# vi /etc/exports 
# pcs resource create ClusterIP ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 ip=10.1.1.30 cidr_netmask=24 op monitor interval=30s
# pcs resource defaults resource-stickiness=100
# pcs resource op defaults timeout=240s
# pcs resource create ClusterSamba lsb:smbd op monitor interval=60s
# pcs resource create ClusterNFS ocf:heartbeat:nfsserver op monitor interval=60s
# pcs resource create DRBD ocf:linbit:drbd drbd_resource=r0 op monitor interval=60s
# pcs resource promotable DRBD promoted-max=1 promoted-node-max=1 clone-max=2 clone-node-max=1 notify=true
# pcs resource create DRBDFS Filesystem device="/dev/drbd1" directory="/exports" fstype="ext4"
# pcs constraint order ClusterIP then ClusterNFS
# pcs constraint order ClusterNFS then ClusterSamba
# pcs constraint order promote DRBD-clone then start DRBDFS
# pcs constraint order DRBDFS then ClusterNFS
# pcs constraint order ClusterIP then DRBD-clone
# pcs constraint colocation ClusterSamba with ClusterIP
# pcs constraint colocation add ClusterSamba with ClusterIP
# pcs constraint colocation add ClusterNFS with ClusterIP
# pcs constraint colocation add DRBDFS with DRBD-clone INFINITY with-rsc-role=Master
# pcs constraint colocation add DRBD-clone with ClusterIP
# pcs cluster stop --all && sleep 2 && pcs cluster start --all
```

Here are configs and stats:

```
cat /etc/drbd.d/r0.res 
resource r0 {
 device /dev/drbd1;
 disk /dev/sdb;
 meta-disk internal;
 net {
  allow-two-primaries;
 }
 on alice {
  address 10.1.1.31:7788;
 }
 on bob {
  address 10.1.1.32:7788;
 } 
}
```

```
cat /etc/corosync/corosync.conf 
totem {
    version: 2
    cluster_name: myCluster
    transport: knet
    crypto_cipher: aes256
    crypto_hash: sha256
}

nodelist {
    node {
        ring0_addr: alice
        name: alice
        nodeid: 1
    }

    node {
        ring0_addr: bob
        name: bob
        nodeid: 2
    }
}

quorum {
    provider: corosync_votequorum
    two_node: 1
}

logging {
    to_logfile: yes
    logfile: /var/log/corosync/corosync.log
    to_syslog: yes
    timestamp: on
}
```

```
pcs status
Cluster name: myCluster
Stack: corosync
Current DC: alice (version 2.0.1-9e909a5bdd) - partition with quorum
Last updated: Fri May 15 12:28:30 2020
Last change: Fri May 15 11:04:50 2020 by root via cibadmin on bob

2 nodes configured
6 resources configured

Online: [ alice bob ]

Full list of resources:

 ClusterIP      (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started alice
 ClusterSamba   (lsb:smbd):     Started alice
 ClusterNFS     (ocf::heartbeat:nfsserver):     Started alice
 Clone Set: DRBD-clone [DRBD] (promotable)
 Masters: [ alice ]
 Stopped: [ bob ]
 DRBDFS (ocf::heartbeat:Filesystem):    Started alice

Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/disabled
  pacemaker: active/disabled
  pcsd: active/enabled
```

```
pcs constraint --full
Location Constraints:
Ordering Constraints:
  start ClusterIP then start ClusterNFS (kind:Mandatory) (id:order-ClusterIP-ClusterNFS-mandatory)
  start ClusterNFS then start ClusterSamba (kind:Mandatory) (id:order-ClusterNFS-ClusterSamba-mandatory)
  promote DRBD-clone then start DRBDFS (kind:Mandatory) (id:order-DRBD-clone-DRBDFS-mandatory)
  start DRBDFS then start ClusterNFS (kind:Mandatory) (id:order-DRBDFS-ClusterNFS-mandatory)
  start ClusterIP then start DRBD-clone (kind:Mandatory) (id:order-ClusterIP-DRBD-clone-mandatory)
  start ClusterIP then promote DRBD-clone (kind:Mandatory) (id:order-ClusterIP-DRBD-clone-mandatory-1)
Colocation Constraints:
  ClusterSamba with ClusterIP (score:INFINITY) (id:colocation-ClusterSamba-ClusterIP-INFINITY)
  ClusterNFS with ClusterIP (score:INFINITY) (id:colocation-ClusterNFS-ClusterIP-INFINITY)
  DRBDFS with DRBD-clone (score:INFINITY) (with-rsc-role:Master) (id:colocation-DRBDFS-DRBD-clone-INFINITY)
  DRBD-clone with ClusterIP (score:INFINITY) (id:colocation-DRBD-clone-ClusterIP-INFINITY)
Ticket Constraints:
```

```
cat /proc/drbd 
version: 8.4.10 (api:1/proto:86-101)
srcversion: 983FCB77F30137D4E127B83 

 1: cs:WFConnection ro:Primary/Unknown ds:UpToDate/DUnknown C r-----
    ns:0 nr:4 dw:8 dr:17 al:1 bm:0 lo:0 pe:0 ua:0 ap:0 ep:1 wo:f oos:4
```

P.S.
I am usually the one who looks for the answers through answered questions, but this one I couldn't find.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the problem with starting the cluster through script which makes sure that drbd is running on both nodes.